# WPF: Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target

Tags: c#, wpf

Can't figure this out, i'm trying to make this Template as versatile as possible. I'm getting the following errors when attempting to centre a TextBlock, HorizontalAlignment doesn't work.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
>   not valid for target property.; Value='0'
>   BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth; DataItem='Grid' (Name='PathGrid');
>   target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='PathPercentage'); target property
>   is 'FontSize' (type 'Double')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
>   not valid for target property.; Value='-6 -6 -6 -6'
>   MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'TextBlock'
>   (Name='PathPercentage'); target property is 'Margin' (type
>   'Thickness')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
>   not valid for target property.; Value='-17 -17 -17 -17'
>   MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'TextBlock'
>   (Name='PathPercentage'); target property is 'Margin' (type
>   'Thickness')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
>   not valid for target property.; Value='83 83 83 83'
>   MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'TextBlock'
>   (Name='PathPercentage'); target property is 'Margin' (type
>   'Thickness')

This is the ControlTemplate with my bindings

```
<Grid x:Name="PathGrid" Margin="2" Width="200">
                        <Canvas>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PathPercentage" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Value}"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       FontSize="{Binding ElementName=PathGrid, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource SizeTextOnParent}}">
                                <TextBlock.Margin>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CenterElement}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="PathGrid" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                        <Binding ElementName="PathPercentage" Path="FontSize"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Margin>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=PathPercentage, Path=Margin}" />
                            <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" 
                                 Stroke="#434953" 
                                 StrokeThickness="3" 
                                 Width="{Binding ElementName=PathGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                                 Height="{Binding ElementName=PathGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" />
```

And here is my converter which should produce margin values which will centre my textblock:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Test_Project.Converters
{
    public class CenterElement : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double parentWidth = (double)values[0];
            double fontSize = (double)values[1];

            double t = Math.Round(((parentWidth / 2) - (fontSize / 2)), 0);
            string margin = t + " " + t + " " + t + " " + t;

            return margin;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Woops, managed to fix it. Just make sure it returns type `Thickness`. I was assuming it should return `Margin` as a type which was why I was struggling find it!

```
double t = Math.Round(((parentWidth / 2) - (fontSize / 2)), 0);
            Thickness margin = new Thickness(t, t, t, t);

            return margin;
```